# Can't create an app on GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine

I can't create an app in GEE.
I have tried with few scripts
but the PUBLISH button stays grey and it should be blue.
I already did 2 apps before.
In the image below you can see the problem:

[Here's the link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/36c738576ff69fe6fca7cf03bd6ec2b8) to the specific script.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must now specify a Google Cloud Project when publishing an app.

Click “CHANGE” under “Google Cloud Project” in the dialog and you will be guided to select or create one.